# Visual Studio Error List Default Sort

Tags: visual-studio

is there a way to force the default sort to sort differently.  I'd like it to sort by category so my errors are ahead of my warnings, but i can't find a way to do this.  When I set the sort order to category, when i hit build selection, it resets.  Interestingly enough, build solution keeps the sort order.  Only build selection resets it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a(VS.80).aspx), it tells us that the "Default Order" column "Displays an integer indicating the order in which an entry was generated."

It seems like you're stuck with it that way.

Comment: Changing the default order isn't necessarily what i want to do. If i can have the check stay on "Category" when i do a build selection, that'll work fine for me.

Comment: I understand.  Its just that on build, it goes to the default sort, and I don't think there's anything you can do about that.

Comment: In [VS 2015 Error List Window page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a(v=vs.140).aspx) there is no "Default Order" column and I couldn't find a way to set the order in which an entry was generated

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2015, if the errors are sorted by a certain column, just click that column heading again once or twice until the arrow disappears to go back to default sorting. You can sort by Severity (errors or warnings) by clicking the column heading over the column that has red and yellow icons for errors and warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click anywhere on the Error List, [Sort By >], [Default Order]

Comment: Hmm... I know this is ancient, but I tried it in VS2015 and it didn't seem to work.  where specifically did you right click?

Comment: In VS2013 right-clicking on any of the column headers worked for me.

Comment: In VS15 there is no [Sort By >] option. @Mike_OBrien, I need not in order of any column, but in order of the build.

Comment: I did that on VS2013